# How to search equal product numbers in two columns from two different excel tables and copy-paste certain cells from matched row to new table

Tags: python, excel

I have two excel tables:

1. old_data.xlsx

   `Product number    Name                Current price    Other columns`

   `1000              Product name 1      10`

   `AB23104           Product name 2      5`

   `430267            Product name 3      20`
2. new_data.xlsx

   `Product number    Name                        New price    Other columns`

   `AB23104           Renamed product name 2      20`

   `1000              Renamed product name 1      5`

   `345LKT10023       Product name 4              100`

***Expected result: table below + 2 feedback messages somewhere***

Message 1) **Product ID 430267 is missing in new data file**

Message 2) **Product ID 345LKT10023 is newly added**

```
    Product ID        Name of product    New price  Old price

    AB23104           Product name 2     20         5

    1000              Product name 1     5          10

    345LKT10023       Product name 4     100        100
```

I have this code for now, but it is not working and not finished due to lack of knowledge on my part:

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd

new_datacols = [0, 1, 2]
old_datacols = [0, 1, 2]

new_data = pd.read_excel('new_data.xlsx', skiprows=1, usecols=new_datacols, index_col=0)
old_data = pd.read_excel('old_data.xlsx', skiprows=1, usecols=old_datacols, index_col=0)

def format_data():
    # combine_type = inner, left, right, outer
    df = pd.merge(new_data, old_data, on='Product number', how='outer')

    df = df.rename(columns={"Product number": "Product ID",
                        "Name": "Name of product",
                        "Current price": "Old price"})

    nan_value = float("NaN")

    df.replace("", nan_value, inplace=True)
    df.dropna(subset=["Name of product"], inplace=True)

    df = df[['Product ID', 'Name of product',
             'New price', 'Old price']]

    print(df.columns)

    # df.to_excel('updated_table.xlsx')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    format_data()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt. It puts the messages in another sheet in the same file. The final spreadsheet looks like this:

[image: Products sheet]

[image: Messages sheet]

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

old_data_filename = r"old_data.xlsx"
new_data_filename = r"new_data.xlsx"
new_spreadsheet_filename = r"updated_products.xlsx"

# Load spreadsheets into a dataframe and set their indexes to "Product number"
old_data_df = pd.read_excel(old_data_filename).set_index("Product number")
new_data_df = pd.read_excel(new_data_filename).set_index("Product number")

# Determine which products are new/missing, and store the corresponding 
# messages in a list, which will be written to its own spreadsheet at the end
old_data_products = set(old_data_df.index)
new_data_products = set(new_data_df.index)

new_products = new_data_products - old_data_products
missing_products = old_data_products - new_data_products

messages = [f"Product ID {product} is missing in new data file" for product in missing_products]
messages.extend(f"Product ID {product} is newly added" for product in new_products)
messages = [f"Message {i}) {message}" for i, message in enumerate(messages, start=1)]

# Keep the original product names
new_data_df.update(old_data_df["Name"])

# Old price is the same as new price unless the product is in old_data_df, in which 
# case it is old_data_df["Current price"]
new_data_df["Old price"] = new_data_df["New price"]
new_data_df["Old price"].update(old_data_df["Current price"])

# Rename the columns
new_data_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
new_data_df.rename(columns={"Product number": "Product ID", 
                            "Name": "Name of product"}, inplace=True)

# Remove all other columns except the ones we want
new_data_df = new_data_df[["Product ID", 
                           "Name of product", 
                           "New price", "Old price"]]

# Write the new products and messages to separate sheets in the same file
with pd.ExcelWriter(new_spreadsheet_filename) as writer:
    new_data_df.to_excel(writer, "Products", index=False)
    pd.DataFrame({"Messages": messages}).to_excel(writer, "Messages", index=False)

# Launch the new spreadsheet
os.startfile(new_spreadsheet_filename)
```

---

EDIT: Code that works with the actual spreadsheets:

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

old_data_filename = r"old_data.xlsx"
new_data_filename = r"new_data.xlsx"
new_spreadsheet_filename = r"updated_products.xlsx"

# Load spreadsheets into a dataframe and set their indexes to "Product number"
old_data_df = pd.read_excel(old_data_filename).set_index("Product ID")
new_data_df = pd.read_excel(new_data_filename).set_index("Product ID")

# Remove duplicated indexes for both the dataframes, keeping only the first occurrence
old_data_df = old_data_df[~old_data_df.index.duplicated()]
new_data_df = new_data_df[~new_data_df.index.duplicated()]

# Determine which products are new/missing, and store the corresponding 
# messages in a list, which will be written to its own spreadsheet at the end
old_data_products = set(old_data_df.index)
new_data_products = set(new_data_df.index)

new_products = new_data_products - old_data_products
missing_products = old_data_products - new_data_products

messages = [f"Product ID {product} is missing in new data file" for product in missing_products]
messages.extend(f"Product ID {product} is newly added" for product in new_products)
messages = [f"Message {i}) {message}" for i, message in enumerate(messages, start=1)]

# Keep the original product names
new_data_df.update(old_data_df["Name"])

# Old price is the same as new price unless the product is in old_data_df, in which 
# case it is old_data_df["Current price"]
new_data_df["Old price"] = new_data_df["New price"]
new_data_df["Old price"].update(old_data_df["Current price"])

# Rename the "Name" column to "Name of product"
new_data_df.rename(columns={"Name": "Name of product"}, inplace=True)

# Remove all other columns except the ones we want
new_data_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
new_data_df = new_data_df[["Product ID", 
                            "Name of product", 
                            "New price", "Old price"]]

# Write the new products and messages to separate sheets in the same file
with pd.ExcelWriter(new_spreadsheet_filename) as writer:
    new_data_df.to_excel(writer, "Products", index=False)
    pd.DataFrame({"Messages": messages}).to_excel(writer, "Messages", index=False)

# Launch the new spreadsheet
os.startfile(new_spreadsheet_filename)
```

Comment: raise ValueError(f"Shape of passed values is {passed}, indices imply {implied}")
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (7278, 8), indices imply (7275, 8)

Comment: What line raises that exception? Post the full traceback.

Comment: Download both tables from this link: **ivolt.bg/media/dev/new_data.xlsx** _and_ **ivolt.bg/media/dev/old_data.xlsx** and run code to see.

Comment: Your spreadsheets are significantly different to what you stated in your original question. It seems the exception was being raised by the call to `new_data_df.update` because there are duplicated Product IDs. I've updated my answer. The code removes these duplicates. You might want to think about whether that's acceptable for you. Have a play around with it.